# powershell does not stop program after timeout

Tags: powershell, timeout

Want to make windows equivalent for GNU timeout (as a oneliner to embed into batch script) to start program and terminate it if this doea on terminate itself after timeout.

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process 'ping.exe' -ArgumentList '127.0.0.1', '-t' -NoNewWindow -PassThru | % { $_.WaitForExit(3000) }; If(!$?) { $_.Kill() }"
```

It only print FALSE after timeout, but ping program continue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` holds the error status for the last *command invocation*, and `$_.WaitForExit(3000)` is not a command.

As evident from the ouput you receive, the `WaitForExit()` method returns `$false` if the target process didn't exit before the timeout was exceeded, so you'll want to inspect *that* value instead:

```
... |% { if(-not $_.WaitForExit(3000)) { $_.Kill() } }
```